# Placing an image under and over another image in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I know, how to cut parts of images and replace or move them.

In this case, I would like to insert a rendered architectural building (e.g. the rendered yellow part in the picture) into its environment. The problem is, that the environment is shown from some perspective and hence parts of the rendering are vanishing behind the environmental image while others are in front.

I had the idea to cut the image along the green line and slide the new image in the direction of the red arrow into this cut. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 layers:

1. Top layer: The building at the right side.
2. Middle layer: The inserted part.
3. Backgroud layer: The original foto.

For the top layer: Duplicate the background image and use a mask to make the left side transparent. The green line in your image is the most relevant part of the mask.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I was wondering, wether there is a directer solution, in which I don't have to cut (and reconnect) the image of the environment.

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider, but in the question you asked if it is possible to "cut the image along the green line and slide the new image in the direction of the red arrow into this cut". This is what my solution does. You could of course mask the Insertion instead (the same mask as in the solution but inverted), but then you can not do the slide part.